# Joomla is constantly exceeding space. Anyone knows why?

Tags: joomla, limit

I have a joomla website hosted on one of my LAMP servers. Somehow joomla is "eating" up drive space and i am constantly receiving the error: "This domains disk limit has been exceeded!"

I tried to increase the disk limit(i use ZPanel) and it worked, but after a few days it went to this error-screen again.
I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Check your logs. Those have taken me down before, namely from too verbose messages such as having debug on. Other than that it is hard to say, unless you look at disk usage from your site. Can't you run: `du -S | sort -n -r` in your web root (then try / if you don't find the culprit)?

Answer (score 0):

Check your files.

- see how /images/ evolved over time (it really depends on how much content you upload) or any other components that create content
- examine /tmp/ and empty it
- check /cache/ folder

Joomla! core files don't usually grow over time in a significant way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. /tmp has a file of 31 bytes while /cache folder an index.html and a folder of 2,5MB. I haven't upload any images since February. Any other sugestions?

Comment: Are you making any backup (like from cpanel?)

Comment: No, i am currently taking external backups to another server. Not storing anything locally.

Comment: Take a look inside your backups - what are the sizes of the directories?  How much space do you allow your site?  What is the size of your biggest directory?  

My recommendation is to take a backup (or copy all the files to your local pc in whichever way you want) then use treesize to figure out where the bulk on your site is coming from.  Obviously it's there, figuring out where and why are the next steps.